# Passing a function address (delegate) to a property

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a generic 'search' window which is used for several database selects. Users can select multiple records from it (by double-clicking the items and checking them). This same window has an 'OK' button. This button confirms the selection from the grid.

I want to find a way for this search window to have some sort of property (i.e.: `Public Property ValidateSelectionFunction As ?`) which can receive a delegate function from another window. Example:

```
Using Search As New SearchWindow
    Search.ValidateSelectionFunction = AddressOf SpecificValidation
    Search.ShowDialog()
End Using
```

Where the SpecificValidation would be a function (of Boolean) validating whatever I want for this specific type of search.

The SearchWindow would contain something like this:

```
Public Class SearchWindow
    Public Property ValidateSelectionFunction As ?

    Private Sub OK_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OK.Click
        If ValidateSelectionFunction IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim Validated As Boolean = ValidateSelectionFunction()
            If Validated Then MsgBox("Validated!")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Of course this is an absurd example. It is just to give an idea of what I'm trying to achive. I'm struggling to find a way to use Delegates for this.

Comment: You have this tagged C#.  It's VB.  Does the code you provided work?  If not, how does it fail (an exception (with a type and a message), does it do nothing)?  Wait, are you looking for a replacement for your `"?"`?.  You need the call signature for the function you want to store.  Look at the `Action` and `Func` delegates

Comment: Declare the property as a [Func<T, TResult>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=net-5.0) type so any function that matches the signature can be assigned.

Comment: Docs: [Delegates (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/delegates/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [Func<T, TResult>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=net-5.0) type so any function that matches the signature can be assigned.

A simplified example (in c#, since you have it tagged) might look like:

```cs
public partial class SearchWindow : Form
{
    // This method can be set by the caller to provide a custom validation method
    public Func<string, bool> Validator { get; set; }

    private void Ok_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Validator != null)
        {
            // txtInput is a TextBox on the search form that contains the text 
            // we want to validate so we pass that to the validator method 
            bool validated = Validator.Invoke(txtInput.Text);

            if (validated)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Validated!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then your calling code might look like:

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // This is the method that we want to pass to the SearchForm
    private bool CustomValidator(string input)
    {
        // Sample validation that input is 5 characteers
        return input?.Length == 5;
    }

    private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SearchWindow search = new SearchWindow())
        {
            // Assign our private validation method to the search form's property
            search.Validator = CustomValidator;
            search.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see you've removed the c# tag now. Let me know if you need this translated...

Comment: It works like a charm. Thanks for your help!